# Cannot store <SCRIPT> tag into database via POST method

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, post

On my web site I have a `TEXTAREA` form tag which is intended to accept some HTML content and store it in MySQL database. Everything works fine except when there's script inside `<SCRIPT></SCRIPT>` tags. If I try to store such a script I get some strange message that I don't have a permission for accessing my php file (containing this TEXTAREA). I can store `<SCRIPT>` tag sontent in my database through cPanel (mySqlAmin console) but not through web form (POST method used). It seems to me that POST method on ISP's Apache server checks POST methods contents. Can somebody explain to me what's going on here and what could be the solution?

This is the exact error message:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /para-actions.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

para-actions.php is the PHP with code that receives POST content from FORM and stores it into database. (As I said, it works fine with all other content except when there's `<SCRIPT>...</SCRIPT>` inside it!)

Even more, the same PHP code works fine on one hosting server and not on another one (the same web hosting provider). The only difference I noticed is that hosting server where I can store `<SCRIPT>` into database uses PHP v5.2.17 while other one which does not allow `<SCRIPT>` uses PHP v5.4.32.

Comment: No solution, when you cannot access the php file

Comment: i have a feeling that this is not the problem. the exact error might be useful, also possibly loaded security modules. are you on a shared hosting environment? encoding before submitting may be a solution. javascript side.

Comment: What, *exactly*, is the error message you are getting? What errors are reported in your server logs?

Comment: One possibility is, Apache mod_security blocks form POST

Comment: Exact error message is this: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /mypage.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Please post the code for the page that is causing the problem. Maybe there is something in the script or the code for your page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this recent question: [Http 406 error on javascript ajax post. Accept header set to accept all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25452586/http-406-error-on-javascript-ajax-post-accept-header-set-to-accept-all/25729736#25729736) one OP had the exact same problem. And Usually mod_security provides some rule for detection of `<script` in POSTed content.

It's quite certainly your problem. And you cannot alter the ISP mod_security rules.

The only thing you can do, as stated in the previous linked answer is to **encode your POST** so that mod_security will not detect the strings inside. Using Base64 encoding is usually the simpliest way of managing it.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a simple test on localhost and it worked using this code

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <?php 
        if ($_POST['data'])
        {
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","abkarino");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO  `abkarino`.`test` (`script`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['data'])."');";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql);    
        }

        ?>
        </head>

        <body>
        <form action="script.php" method="post">
        <textarea name="data" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

and it worked with no error.

which means: 1) you have something wrong with your code.

or 2) mod_security is preventing it to get rid of injecting scripts to your page just like what  Nikhil Mohan said.

Comment: Yes it seems that mod_security prevents XSS injection but how to prove that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you're allowing your users to upload a script, or something, but can't have them type the tags tell them to write the script without the tags. When you post the script add the tags yourself.

a robust method would be allow them to do what they want. If they type the script with tags parse the content and remove the scripts tags before putting it in the DB. There must be a regex function that will allow you to search their entered content for `<script>` and replace it with ' '. Then search for `</script>` and replace it with ' '. Then you'll have tagless content to put in your db, or on your page.

try

```
mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit =  -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

Hope that's at least somewhere in the ballpark of what you're trying to do, lol.

Answer (score -2):

Please do encoding and decoding before POST by using base64_encode and base64_decode the result.