# Http 406 error on javascript ajax post. Accept header set to accept all

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apache

I am getting an error from the server when I try to make an AJAX request that I cannot figure out. It is an HTTP 406 error. From what I understand this means that the server cannot send a response in the format that the Accept header indicates. But from what I can see, I am `Accept`ing `*/*` (wildcard).

You can see the details of my HTTP request in this image.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTfBf.png
[image: My HTTP Request]

This is my PHP code for the page:

```
<body>
<div id="container">

             (snip - menu and header)

    <div id="notify-saved">
        <div class="width">
            <span>Saved!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="confirm-delete">
        <div id="confirm-delete-content" class="width">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-separator">
    </div>
    <div id="body" class="width">

        <section id="content">
            <br />
    <form method="POST" id='template-form' action="post-actions.php" >
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value="15" />
        <input type='text' name='name' value="default-scripting" placeholder='Name' />
            <br />
            <br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='major' id="majorminor" />
        <textarea name='value' style="width:100%;">&lt;script src=&quot;http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</textarea>
            <br />
            <br />

        <button name='action' value="Update Template" id='update-button' >Update</button>



    </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
// Attach a submit handler to the form
$( "#update-button" ).click( function( event ) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $('#template-form');
    var template_id = $form.find( "input[name='id']" ).val();
    var template_name = $form.find( "input[name='name']" ).val();
    var template_value = $form.find( "textarea[name='value']" ).val();

    var template_is_major = 'minor';
    if( $( "input[name='major']" ).prop('checked') ){
        template_is_major = "major";
    }

    var url = $form.attr( "action" );

    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post( url, {  id: template_id, name: template_name, value: template_value, major: template_is_major, action: "Update Template"  } );

    // Show that the request has completed successfully
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        $('#notify-saved').slideDown(200).delay(500).slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

.

Also of relevance is the fact that this error *only happens some of the time*, for instance if the template-value submitted is

`&lt;script src=&quot;http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;`

then there will be an error, but if the leading `<` is omitted, then there is no error:

`script src=&quot;http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;`

The receiving php looks like this (post-actions.php):

```
<?php 

    // ugly-@$$ anti-magicquotes hackk
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $process = array(&$_GET, &$_REQUEST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
        while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
            foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
                unset($process[$key][$k]);
                if (is_array($v)) {
                    $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                    $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
                } else {
                    $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
                }
            }
        }
        unset($process);
    }


    require_once('database.php');
    $dbo = new Database();

    if( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ){

        switch( $_REQUEST['action'] ){

            (snip - many irrelevant cases)

            case "Update Template":
                $dbo->UpdateTemplate( $_REQUEST[DB_TEMPLATES_ID], $_REQUEST[DB_TEMPLATES_NAME],
                $_REQUEST[DB_TEMPLATES_VALUE], $_REQUEST[DB_TEMPLATES_MAJOR] );
                break;



        }

    }
```

And the database class:

```
<?php 

require_once ("config.php");
require_once ("database-contract.php");

class Database {

    protected $db;
    protected $pdo;

    function __construct(){
        $this->db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        if($this->db->connect_errno > 0){
            die('Unable to connect to database [' . $this->db->connect_error . ']');
        }

        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS );
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }

    function __destruct(){
        $this->db->close();
        $this->pdo = null;
    }


        $query = 'INSERT INTO `'.DB_TEMPLATES.'` ( `'.DB_TEMPLATES_NAME.'` ) VALUES ( :name )';

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

    }

    function updateTemplate($id, $name, $value, $major ){

        if( $major == "major" ){ $major = 1; }
        else{ $major = 0; }

        $query = 'UPDATE `'.DB_TEMPLATES.'` 
                    SET 
                    `'.DB_TEMPLATES_NAME.'`=:name,
                    `'.DB_TEMPLATES_VALUE.'`=:value,
                    `'.DB_TEMPLATES_MAJOR.'`=:major
                    WHERE
                    `'.DB_TEMPLATES_ID.'`=:id';

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue(":value", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue(":major", $major, PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $stmt->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );

        $stmt->execute();

    }


        $query = '  DELETE FROM '.DB_TEMPLATES.'
                    WHERE
                    '.DB_TEMPLATES_ID.'=:id';

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute();


    }

    (snip - irrelevant functions)

}
```

At certain points along the way, I had thought this may have been a character encoding issue, but I don't think that any more. Perhaps it is some odd character escaping issue? Other posts here on SO seem to indicate it is a configuration issue / (feature?) of apache's mod_security. I tried disabling a few different things but that did not work, and now I am just at a loss as for what to think.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your `php` echoing?

Comment: Well the php script is saved as UTF-8. but php info has default_charset no value no value

Comment: No, it must be something different. Like you echoing JSON or something?...

Comment: There is supposed to be a blank response from the server (unless there is an error)

Comment: further to that point, the it does some times work properly, and send an empty (success) response, other times it does not, depending on what the value of the form is

Comment: And if the response is empty, there is no `406`?

Comment: Well correct, but perhaps backwards. The intended response is a blank response, so if everything works properly, I will get a blank response, with HTTP status 200. When things go wrong, I get a 406 error as seen in the linked image

Comment: It really depends what your `PHP` is doing. You gotta post it. Please...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59830/discussion-between-carczar-and-user32342534).

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the PHP code with X-debug to find out the root?

Comment: @Tyler Eich Please be careful with your edits. You had changed the meaning of my question to inaccurately portray my problem. Specifically with the character escaping of my input - they were meant to be escaped. Also, for the most part, your "beautification" of my code was only changing from one coding style to another.

Comment: @Mysteryos Thanks for the suggestion. I did not end up using this, but am glad to know about this tool in case I need it in the future.

Comment: @CarCzar My apologies! While I do feel the "beautification" improved readability, I did not mean to change the meaning of your post. Thanks for politely correcting my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you have a 406, and also the fact that this is based on the presence of the `<` before the word *script*, leads directly to a security filter in action. So **mod_security** and **apache** configuration files would be more useful than the js/php code to find the root blocking rule.

This looks like an anti-xss filter. Maybe a very simple one like:

```
SecFilter "<( |\n)*script"
```

If you can alter this mod_security configuration, then do that... or don't. It's about *security*. Maybe you should keep theses filter in place to protect your application for really unwanted script injections. Maybe the real solution is that your official application forms should manage communications with the server without being *suspicious* for mod_security. And here your POST is too much like a Cross Site Scripting attack for a tool which is only reading the stream and detect a javascript call inside.

You could for example add a base64 encoding on the POSTed value (from the js) and decode the result on the PHP side, some base64 encoding js libraries are available on github.

You could in fact apply any transformation on your data that render this data HTML-free (and Javascript-free), at least for the HTTP filtering tools. And Base64 is usually the solution, but check how the used library manage encoding of utf-8 characters, the *real* base64 was ascii only.

Comment: I have tried disabling mod_security altogether (with .htaccess) to no avail. However, implementing base64 encoding has indeed solved my problem. I'm not sure whether to consider it a fix or a work around, but it does work now. Thank you! I will award you the bounty in the next few days if no better solution comes up. Edit. Haha. I just went to up-vote you, but have not enough rep left after the bounty to do so. :(

Comment: Spot on! Great answer

Comment: @CarCzar, 200 is a big investment, indeed. Especially because theses first steps are associated with a lot of actions grants. I hope you'll get theses reputation back soon.

Comment: @regilero No prob. I'm just glad to have this sorted :)

Comment: I had a case 406-case. I solved it by masking the characters < _ ( { [ = with other characters. On the serverside they get converted back. I tried the base64-js-version before. But that didnt work because my data were too much.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I will tell you how I debugged it and fixed it.

In my case I could reproduce the forbidden response by writting some very specific inline css directives (inside a style attribute in an html tag).

I analized the error log file of apache (in my case it is at `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log` and filtered only by the response code I was getting.

```
grep 406 error_log
```

The explanation said it was a rule by ModSecurity, this is what it said:

```
[Mon Jan 02 13:21:10.394376 2017] [:error] [pid 12827:tid 139784907347712] [client 255.255.255.255] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 2). Pattern match "(?: (?:height|width) ?(?:=|\\\\:) ?[0-9] ?px|overflow ?: ?(?:auto|hidden)|style ?= ?\\"? ?display ?: ?none ?)" at ARGS:body. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2/30_asl_antispam.conf"] [line "174"] [id "300076"] [rev "29"] [msg "Atomicorp.com WAF AntiSpam Rules: Hidden Text Detected"] [data " height:8px"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [hostname "my.website.mx"] [uri "/index.php"] [unique_id "WGqoJqwQ25oAADIbgkcAAAGP"]
```

I investigated how to disable this and it turns out you can add this in a conf file:

```
<Location "/">
    SecRuleRemoveById 300076
</Location>
```

Problem solved for me. Note, if you want to disable more than one rule you can separate the ids by spaces.